# runtime error with str:replace() function in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using `str:replace()` function in xslt 1.0. It is working fine with some of the cases. In one of the case, I'm using `replace()` to modify node's value in an xml file and it is throwing this error:

```
runtime error: file http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.function.xsl line 24 element copy-of
Cannot add an attribute node to a non-element node.
```

I'm accessing the `replace()` function by importing this extended funationality:

```
<xsl:import href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.function.xsl"/>
```

Can anyone spot some of the obvious mistakes I may have done unintentionally to trigger this?

Meanwhile I'm trying to make a sample example `xsl` file to show the attempted code lines. I'm trying to visualize the situation using the `--verbose` command line feature available in `xsltproc` command.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Martin, by just adding `string()` around the replacement parameter solved the runtime error, something like this:

```
str:replace(string, object, string(object))
```

I have two subsequent questions:

1. how adding the string() is solving the issue here?
2. Now it is working, but after replacing, I have to match the updated-element against `key()` but it is giving `false` even when the updated-element is already in key-set, is it possible that `replace()` is somehow changing the element in some sense?

For example:
I have already "alpha.beta" in my key() and by replacing an element "alpha.gamma" to "alpha.beta" using `str:replace()`, somehow the key() is returning false for this case?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please ask the key related problem in a new question, showing the code you have, the result or error you get and the result you expect.

Comment: @MartinHonnen created a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026855/xslt-key-function-retuning-false-on-valid-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation/specification http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/index.html clearly says: "It is an error if any of the nodes in the replacement node list are attribute nodes or namespace nodes.". So it seems you have an attribute node in the replacement node list which is not supported. Perhaps you only need one single replacement as a string and that way can just use `string(@att)` for that parameter.

Lines 23-25 in your linked library do

```
     <xsl:variable name="replace-nodes-rtf">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$replace" />
     </xsl:variable>
```

so stuffing an attribute node into a variable that way is not possible and is causing the failure.