# xslt key() function returning false on valid node?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using `XSLT` 1.0 on my xml file. For one of the change, I have to first replace a substring of node's value with another string and then call `key()` on it.

Suppose the node value is 'alpha.beta', then after using `str:replace()` following the suggestion on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011618/runtime-error-with-strreplace-function-in-xslt), the value is updated to be 'alpha.gamma'. Later I'm calling `key()` on it which is returning false for the case where node is actually there in `key()`.

The example I tried which led me to doubt that maybe replace() is changing the element is some sense:

```
Case1:
pass the string 'alpha.gamma' directly to the key()
key(some-defined-key, 'alpha.gamma') returns true

Case2:
update the variable var from 'alpha.beta' to 'alpha.gamma' and pass the variable
key(some-defined-key, $var) returns false
```

I printed the node's value at each step to make sure that node's value is getting updated correctly. So,

1. Is there some kind of shortcoming of key() function in xslt 1.0?
2. Is there some possibility that replace() changed the node is some sense?
3. Is there a way to find out the cause?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to prototype the exact scenario, please bear with me. First I have a xsl file containing list of fruits I want to eat stored with the help of local-namespace:

local-namespace.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:lcl="my_local_namespace"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <lcl:fruits>
        <lcl:fruit>apple</lcl:fruit>
        <lcl:fruit>banana</lcl:fruit>
    </lcl:fruits>

    <xsl:variable name="fruits-list" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/lcl:fruits/lcl:fruit"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I have a xml file showing fruits available, lets call it fruits.xml:

```
<fruits>
    <fruit-available>
        <fruit name="fresh-apple"></fruit>
        <fruit name="fresh-banana"></fruit>
    </fruit-available>
    <fruit-selector>fresh-${FRUIT-NAME}</fruit-selector>
</fruits>
```

Now, using the `fruit-selector` node's value, I have to replace `${FRUIT-NAME}` with each of the fruits I want to eat(i.e. lcl:fruit elements) and if the fruit is not present in the `fruit-available` node then generate an error tag saying that particular fruit is not available.

the fruits.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:lcl="my_local_namespace"
    xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="local-namespace.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.function.xsl"/>

    <xsl:key name="fruitsKey" match="fruits/fruit-available/fruit" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Errors>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Errors>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="CheckFruits">
        <xsl:param name="fruitElement"/>
        <xsl:param name="currentFruit"/>
        <xsl:variable name="selector" select="str:replace($fruitElement, '${FRUIT-NAME}', string($currentFruit))"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(key('fruitsKey', $selector))">
            <Error><xsl:value-of select="concat('Fruit element: ', $selector, ' is not available')"/></Error>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fruits/fruit-selector">
        <xsl:variable name ="currentfruitElement" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$fruits-list">
        <xsl:call-template name="CheckFruits">
            <xsl:with-param name="fruitElement" select="$currentfruitElement"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="currentFruit" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I suspected the `key()` is showing false even with the valid case:

**Execution result:**

```
xsltproc --xinclude fruits.xsl fruits.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Errors xmlns:lcl="my_local_namespace" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
  <Error>Fruit element: fresh-apple is not available</Error>
  <Error>Fruit element: fresh-banana is not available</Error>
</Errors>
```

**NOTE:**
I'm a beginner so even if the mistake is pretty straightforward, I'm interested in understanding the concept involved.

Comment: Please show a minimal but complete XSLT sample as well, demonstrating the problem. A key is built on an input document, any intermediary result is in XSLT 1.0 first of all a result tree fragment. You can convert it to a node-set but it will be a different document than the input document. We really need to see how your key is declared, how you apply the changes and where/how you use the key function.

Comment: Without providing a way to reproduce the problem, all you can hope for are guesses. My guess would be that the easy solution is to reverse the order of actions: first get the nodes you want using a key, then replace the parts you want to be replaced. -- In any case, an XSL transformation operates on the input tree - and this tree is NEVER modified by the transformation. All that the transformation does is write the result to the output tree.

Comment: That is not "a minimal but complete XSLT sample, demonstrating the problem".

Comment: A side note: the specification for the EXSLT str:replace() function states that the result should be a node-set. I have tested the implementation at http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.function.xsl and it does conform.

Comment: We also need to know what XSLT processor you are using. The implementation of `str:replace()` that you are calling invokes `func:function` which is an extension to the spec, that may be implemented differently in some processors than in others. Generally you're in very processor-dependent territory here - things would be clearer if you moved to XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following example makes sense to you:

**XML**

```
<fruits>
    <fruit-available>
        <fruit name="fresh-apple"/>
        <fruit name="fresh-banana"/>
    </fruit-available>
    <fruit-selector>fresh-${FRUIT-NAME}</fruit-selector>
</fruits>
```

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT (assuming libxslt processor)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
xmlns:lcl="my_local_namespace"
exclude-result-prefixes="str lcl">

<xsl:import href="http://exslt.org/str/functions/replace/str.replace.function.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<lcl:fruits>
    <lcl:fruit>apple</lcl:fruit>
    <lcl:fruit>pear</lcl:fruit>
    <lcl:fruit>banana</lcl:fruit>
</lcl:fruits>

<xsl:key name="available-fruit" match="fruit" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="/fruits">
    <xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />
    <xsl:variable name="fruit-selector" select="fruit-selector" />
    <Errors>
        <xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/lcl:fruits/lcl:fruit">
            <xsl:variable name="key" select="str:replace($fruit-selector, '${FRUIT-NAME}', string(.))"/>
            <!-- switch context back to XML in order to use key -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$xml">
                <xsl:if test="not(key('available-fruit', $key))">
                    <Error>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
                    </Error>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Errors>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Errors>
  <Error>fresh-pear</Error>
</Errors>
```

Comment: I got the basic idea, can you conclude this with a bit of explanation to avoid similar thing? Or shouldn't there be a basic check within `xslt` to give a `WARNING` that you are calling the `key()` in the wrong context?

Comment: I don't know how you could avoid a similar thing other than being aware of what you're doing. There is no way that XSLT can know you're calling the key in the "wrong" context, because it is not a mind reader and has no idea what you're doing at the conceptual level. There is nothing unusual in calling a key and getting an empty node-set as the result. Even in your own example, you could receive an XML that does not have any available fruits matching your hard-coded ones. After all, that's why you're running the transformation in the first place, is it not?

Comment: @DonBaka XSLT 2.0 recognised the problems in the design of the key() function by adding a third parameter that defines the document you want to search. Sadly (a) you can't make retrospective changes to a spec, and (b) many users like you are still using the original 1.0 standard from 1999, with all its flaws.

Comment: hello, I posted a question here, can you have a quick look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687831/xsltproc-not-supporting-path-cmdline-argument

Comment: @DonBaka Please don't do that.

Comment: Acknowledged, sorry. Stackoverflow is not letting me post question here due to some bad voted questions

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong because you haven't supplied all the code, but you need to understand how `key()` works when there are multiple documents. The `str:replace()` function returns newly constructed nodes in a newly constructed document. The `key()` function only searches the document that contains the context node. It won't search the document created by `str:replace()` unless the context node is a node in that document.

I'm also concerned by your statement "I printed the node's value at each step to make sure that node's value is getting updated correctly". I don't know exactly what you did, but the way you've written this suggests that you haven't fully appreciated that nodes are immutable. In XSLT, nodes are never updated; you perform a transformation by creating an amended copy.